# Heroku giving 404 on image

Tags: javascript, heroku

I just deployed an app through Heroku and while the background images are displaying the element images are not.  I am getting a 404 error.  Seeking help, please.

Comment: Can you post some more information about your app that could help us see what might be wrong?  Preferably a slimmed-down full example.

Comment: Nobody can help you with a one sentence issue like this and no debugging information

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you deploy the web app to heroku. It tries to minimize and precompile all files and store them in assets folder(or different folder name) with different names. I do not know what kind of framework you are using for your website.

If you are using Ruby On Rails framework, I recommend that you create images folder in public and store all your images here (this is the easiest way).